# How can I use a named scope in my model against an array of items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, model, collect

I know that I can do a query for recent books based on an array as in

`scope :recent_books, lambda {|since_dt| {:conditions=>{:created_at >= since_dt}}}`

but how can I do a similar query when I have an array of items, e.g. what if I want to know if there any records that match the dates in an array of [date1, date2, date3, etc.]

I think there must be a collect/inject/select/map y method that'll do it but I am not sure which from reading them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you pass an array as the value, ActiveRecord is smart enough to compare for inclusion in the array. For example,

```
Book.where(:author_id => [1, 7, 42])
```

produces a SQL query with a `WHERE` clause similar to:

```
WHERE "author_id" IN (1, 7, 42)
```

You can take advantage of this in a `scope` the same way you would set normal conditions:

```
class Book < ....
  # Rails 3
  scope :by_author, lambda { |author_id| where(:author_id => author_id) }

  # Rails 2
  named_scope :by_author, lambda { |author_id
    { :conditions => {:author_id => author_id} }
  }
end
```

Then you can pass a single ID or an array of IDs to `by_author` and it will just work:

```
Book.by_author([1,7,42])
```

Comment: Although I know the syntax changed a bit from rails2's `named_scope`, would the lambda approach work ok in rails2?  Thx, Michael.

Comment: Yeah. I first used this syntax with Rails 2 myself, including some named scopes that matched against arrays. You'll just have to change the `where` call to a `conditions` hash.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I added an example of how you would do it with Rails 2.

Comment: @David And do you know how to work with a array of tuples like [[1,2],[3,2]]. I need to work with the first and second value of each tuple separately.

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 4, I can check for the inclusion of a string in an array attribute by using a scope like this:

```
scope :news, -> { where(:categories => '{news}') }
```

Or with an argument:

```
scope :by_category, ->(category) { where(:categories => "{#{category}}") }
```

Comment: thanks, this helped me a lot.  the { } around the {news} makes all the difference.  Wasn't familar with that syntax..